# Display different values at different angles in a circle using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, degrees

Using HTML5 Canvas and Javascript I need to display different values (represented by a dot maybe) at different angles inside a circle.

Example data:
val 34% @ 0°,
val 54% @ 12°,
val 23% @ 70°,
and so on...

If I have a canvas 300 x 300px and the center of the circle is located at x: 150px and y: 150px with a radius of 150px, how would I calculate where to set my dot for the value 54% at 12 degrees?

My math is kinda terrible xD

I'd appreciate any kind of help and please ask questions if I do not make myself clear enough.

Thank you for listening and thank you in advance for you deep insights :D

EDIT (to explain in more detail):

Here is an image to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish:
[image: Illustration: values at different angles/degrees]

I hope this makes my question a little more understandable.
(As you can see, not the same values as above)

Ty for your patience!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use this to convert from polar (radius, angle) coordinates to cartesian ones :

```
// θ : angle in [0, 2π[
function polarToCartesian(r, θ) {
    return {x: r*Math.cos(θ), y: r*Math.sin(θ)};
}
```

For example, if you want to draw at 12°, you may compute the point like this :

```
var p = polarToCartesian(150, 12*2*Math.PI/360);
p.x += 150; p.y += 150;
```

**EDIT :** my `polarToCartesian` function takes [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) as input, as many function in the Canvas API. If you're more used to degrees, you may need this :

```
 function degreesToRadians(a) {
     return Math.PI*a/180;
 }
```

Comment: This looks pretty good, any chance of a jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: @dystroy Ty for you quick answer, sadly it does not solve my problem all the way. I've updated my question to further explain what I'm trying to accomplish :) Ty for you patience! :D

Comment: I think I gave you the needed elements. Do you have a remaining problem ? SO won't write your whole software.

Comment: +1 fantastic demo that will be really useful for lots of developers! @LinusPersson you should be able to do what you need from this.

Comment: @dystroy Yes I understand you do not want to give me my whole software and I would not want that either. This is just a small part of what I need to do later. Thing is, as I said, my math is kinda shitty, I do not know how to manipulate your code to render a dot @ 12° where the dot is located at say 50% of the radius. I might have to go back to school again and learn some more math haha xD

Comment: @dystroy I'm sorry for all the trouble, your code did of course work fine and thank you a lot for the help and patience. Had some errors in my own code that made it seem like your code didn't work. Sorry again! If I could I'd give you lots more than a up vote and mark for correct answer. Ty!

Comment: Good. Glad to know this was useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mithun/nArUN/1/))

```
var can = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var drawAngledLine = function(x, y, length, angle) {
    var radians = angle / 180 * Math.PI;
    var endX = x + length * Math.cos(radians);
    var endY = y - length * Math.sin(radians);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y)
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

var drawCircle = function(x, y, r) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

var drawDot = function(x, y, length, angle, value) {
    var radians = angle / 180 * Math.PI;
    var endX = x + length*value/100 * Math.cos(radians);
    var endY = y - length*value/100 * Math.sin(radians);
    drawCircle(endX, endY, 2);
}

var drawText = function(x, y, length, angle, value) {
    var radians = angle / 180 * Math.PI;
    var endX = x + length*value/100 * Math.cos(radians);
    var endY = y - length*value/100 * Math.sin(radians);
    console.debug(endX+","+endY);
    ctx.fillText(value+"%", endX+15, endY+5);
    ctx.stroke();
}

var visualizeData = function(x, y, length, angle, value) {

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#999";
    ctx.lineWidth = "1";
    drawAngledLine(x, y, length, angle);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#0a0";
    drawDot(x, y, length, angle, value);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#666";
    ctx.font = "bold 10px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    drawText(x, y, length, angle, value);
}

ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF0B3";
drawCircle(150, 150, 150);

visualizeData(150, 150, 150, 0, 34);
visualizeData(150, 150, 150, 12, 54);
visualizeData(150, 150, 150, 70, 23)

visualizeData(150, 150, 150, 120, 50);
visualizeData(150, 150, 150, -120, 80);
visualizeData(150, 150, 150, -45, 60);
```

Comment: Thank you! Already got the problem solved though :D Thanks again for your time!